# Dividing Grid by Numbers

Tags: visual, pencil-and-paper-games

Separate the grids below into groups of squares, such that:

1. Each group contains exactly one numeral.
2. The number of squares equals the numeral in the group.

For example:

[image: Example]

Could be solved liked this:

[image: Solution]

Hopefully this isn't too easy! There may be more than one solution for each grid.

[image: Puzzle 1]
[image: Puzzle 2]
[image: Puzzle 3]

Comment: The puzzles seem too unconstrained to have unique solutions. You might want to take a look at [Nurikabe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurikabe), which has a similar idea with additional constraints.

Comment: Whoops, that was supposed to link to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurikabe_(puzzle)

Comment: I learnt 2 new things so not complaining :D

Comment: *easy* and *mot unique* are not necessarily *bad*. I think it is a nice puzzle, and as you have said yourself in the meantime: you can make harder variants the next time.

Comment: Fillomino is another similar puzzle type.

Comment: Your puzzles are similar to puzzles called Cell Blocks which have been published in The Times (of London).  I am not sure if they still publish them.  In the Cell Blocks puzzles, the group of squares must form either a rectangle or a square.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution to all 3:

> [image]

Sorry it's a bit sloppy but conveys the idea adequately. I either got lucky or am good at these (or they were easy and had multiple solutions), I had to backtrack like twice total for all three.

Comment: Wow that was quick! Looks like there are quite a few solutions, I'll have to find a way to make it harder.

Answer (score 3):

Simple guess work with no pure logic and easily done.

> [image] [image] [image]

Some suggetions to make it harder and the solution unique:

- If say a number is 7, add multiple sevens to ensure that all the 7's form a part of the same block or probably a wall of one of the block. Use different colour to help in distinguishability. ([Pseudoku: A Game of Finding Order in Chaos](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6048/pseudoku-a-game-of-finding-order-in-chaos))
- Remove a number, say just have 1-7 and remove 8. Let the user figure out where to place 8.
- border issues: Add constraints that

  - 2 cannot border its multiples likewise for 3.
  - A number cannot border its consecutive number, etc.

Many ways to make this what you intend to. Put your thinking cap and puzzle us :)

Comment: Aww I was hoping it would take longer.. Let me know if you've got any suggestions on making it more challenging :)

Comment: Please find my comments to metamorphose the puzzle to a newer level. Just a few for you to get started :)

Comment: Wow thanks so much! I really like the idea of not being able to border consecutive numbers. I might have a go at adding/removing the numbers as well and see how that affects it. I thought of making each block more like a snake with a number at the start and end, but then I realised there's already game really similar to that...

Comment: a minor mistake in last image label **8** contains `7` squares and label **5** contains `6` ;)

Answer (score 2):

It does seem pretty easy, and I imagine there are a lot of solutions for each one.

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

These may also contribute to the answers.

> [image: Image 1]

> [image: Image 2]

> [image: Image 3]

Comment: I like the colours!